# Desarrollar una pregunta que requiera fecha

Tags: python

Una ayuda, estoy trabajando en un proyecto y me piden ingresar el campo fecha mediante una pregunta estoy intentando y siempre sale error. Me podrían guiar:

```
fecha = date(input("Fecha de Contratación: "))
print("{}".format(fecha("%d-%m-%y")))
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 3):

Antes que nada, me gustaría comentarte que el método `input()` sólo puede tomar texto. Tienes que encontrar una manera de analizar ese texto y convertirlo en una fecha o bien, utilizar librerías externas.

---

Ahora bien, aquí te adjunto dos posibles soluciónes a tu problema :

**Opción 1 - Utiliza librería dateutil**

Utilizando la librería `dateutil` puedes "parsear" los string a fechas :

```
from dateutil import parser
date = parser.parse(input("Entra una fecha : "))
```

**Opción 2 - Input de usuario**

Esta opción, considero que es menos rentable que la anterior. Aquí, simplemente pide al usuario que introduzca la fecha en un formato específico, y luego convierte ese formato en los tres números para el año, el mes y el día :

```
date_entry = input('Entra la fehca en este formato : YYYY-MM-DD')
year, month, day = map(int, date_entry.split('-'))
date1 = datetime.date(year, month, day)
```

Comment: Si necesitas cualquier aclaración / ayuda escribe un comentario

Comment: voy a realizar la prueba y te comentare gracias por el aporte

Comment: Perfecto, espero una respuesta !

Answer (score 0):

Si no te importa que la fecha esté en un formato especifico, ofrezco otra forma más:

#### Propuesta

###### Código

```
from datetime import datetime

# Le pido una fecha al usuario.
fecha_como_texto = input("Ingrese una fecha en formato DD-MM-YYYY: ")

# Convierto esa fecha que está como texto a un objeto datetime (fecha y hora)
# Si la fecha no es del formato pedido, lanzará un ValueError (que puedes capturar con un try - except)
fecha_y_hora = datetime.strptime(fecha_como_texto, "%d-%m-%Y")

# convierto el datetime a un objeto date (fecha)
fecha = fecha_y_hora.date()

print(fecha)
```

###### Produce

```
Ingrese una fecha en formato DD-MM-YYYY: 12-12-2020
2020-12-12
```

---

El código está separado en partes para poder explicar mejor lo que hace, pero en realidad, podría escribirse en una sola linea así:

```
from datetime import datetime

fecha = datetime.strptime(input("Ingrese una fecha en formato DD-MM-YYYY: "), "%d-%m-%Y").date()
```

#### Referencias

- [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)
- [datetime.date()](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.date)